# element click intercepted exception in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am a beginner in selenium and having a tough time understanding one of the errors appearing while using selenium chromedriver in python.

So, I am trying to click an element inside an svg tag by using css_selector. But I am getting ElementClickInterceptedException with the error **(... is not clickable at point (1281, 60). Other element would receive the click:...)**.  However, if I am putting **time.sleep(5)** before clicking the element, then I am able to click it. Why is it happening?

My first guess was maybe the element is not becoming visible or is inside an invisible box and I have to wait. Hence I tried to handle it with the explicit wait. But both cases timed out. So I assumed, it was not due to that. But then it is difficult for me to guess the reason, as time.sleep(5) is working.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks like the webpage has a hidden element that acts as a overlay, You will have to retrieve the exact `id` or `class` name of the element and execute it via Javascript.
 `driver.execute_script(document.getElementsByName('#MYID')[0].click();)`

Comment: @SalmanFarsi Thanks for the input. But then why waiting before clicking is solving the problem? Shouldn't the problem stay even after waiting?

Comment: Because when you wait, the Javascript in the page is auto hiding the overlay after the page loads entirely, using the `window.onload`. If you want to click the button before this happens, You should use the `execute_javascript` method.

Comment: Thanks, @SalmanFarsi. I got the idea but I think I need to do more study to understand what you have suggested and implement it. I will continue my research on this.

Comment: What exactly `explicit wait` have you tried?

Comment: @Prophet I used this command which timed out. `WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#embedded-app > div > div > div > div.dropins-previewer-header-container > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > button > span > svg')))`. So this is the element that was receiving the click instead of the element which is located inside.